# Alternating cron jobs issue

Tags: linux, cron

I am trying to get cron jobs to run on alternate days...so if one runs today, the other will run tomorrow and so on. I know

```
* * */2 * * command
```

will run every other day...but i need the other one to be offset through out the year no matter what date...any thoughts what command would run on the alternate days?

Comment: I just ended up using php and wrote two scripts for each process <?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

function get_current_day() {

$then = mktime ( 0 , 0, 0, 1,1,'00');
$now = time();

$days = ($now - $then ) / 86400 - 1;

return (int) $days;

}

$i= get_current_day();

if(($i % 2)==0)
{
echo "run it today";

shell_exec('php /data/1.php');
}


?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an expression to get you started

```
if ((c=`date -d 3/13/2012 -u +%s` / 86400 % 2 == 1)); then echo odd; else echo even; fi
```

The command `date -u +%s` returns the seconds since `1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC`. The `-u` option makes it use UTC for both the start and end time, so the result is independent of timezone.  Then it divides by 86400 to calculate number of days, then determines if it's even or odd.  The return code will be 0 (shell true) for odd and 1 (shell false) for even.

This has the advantage over other solutions in that it won't give you two evens or odds in a row at a month or year boundary with an odd number of days since it's counting from 1/1/1970 without regard to years or months.

Note that this method is not perfect.  Due to the occasional leap-second having been added, this method could make the wrong decision within a few seconds of midnight.

Answer (score 0):

I know of two ways, both of which are ugly in a different way.

There is brute force:

```
0 0 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30 * * command
0 0 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31 * * command
```

I didn't type those numbers, so it feels okay to use the solution.

Then there's the wrapper script that refuses to run except on its designated day. Put this in `/usr/local/bin/event`, and symlink it to `/usr/local/bin/odd

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(basename $0)" = "even" ]; then
  EXIT_ON_MATCH=1
else
  EXIT_ON_MATCH=0
fi

if [ "$(expr $(($(date --utc +%s)/86400)) % 2)" = "$EXIT_ON_MATCH" ]; then
  exit 1
fi

$@
```

then do

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/even command
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/odd command
```

Replace `0 0` with some reasonable time.

Comment: I offer a Zen bow to the enlightened spirit of anyone who can turn the even/odd script into a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the following BASH one-liner as your cron command.  I used $HOME/mycron as the file in which to store the number of the next command to run, but you can set that to any location/file that's writable by the user running the cron job.  Replace the "echo 'run cmd1'" and "echo 'run cmd2'" parts with the actual commands that run your second and first commands (yes, that order is intentional).

```
0 6 * * * if [ -e $HOME/mycron ]; then WHICH=`cat $HOME/mycron`; if [ $WHICH -eq 2 ]; then echo 'run cmd2'; echo 1 > $HOME/mycron; else echo 'run cmd1'; echo 2 > $HOME/mycron; fi; fi
```

Comment: Don't see why it wouldn't work, but I prefer stateless so I don't have to worry about messed up permissions, full disk, etc. Also, I'd recommend putting the one liner into a script.